# Java JAR File and Database Connection

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, database-connection, netbeans-8

I would like to ask a question about jar and database connection. I performed an application and converted to jar file. Jar file works if I open NetBeans's Service which is server(I have created my tables on jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample). But I want to open jar file without opening NetBeans and its service server. The application should work on other PCs if the jar file clicks.

I have searched a lot about this but I do not know how I can do. For example, if I use file database (MSAccess) with ucanaccess driver, will this support JPA(Entity Beans) and JDBC ? Because I have used JPA and JDBC together in my application. I have also searched embedded database but when I create the embedded database and table, I can not access table. It gives me an error which is "Table/View does not exist".

Please help me.
What should I do if I use JDBC and JPA together in my application ?
And If I want to open the jar file other PCs and they can reach database information, what should I do ?

Best regards.

Comment: JAR or War ? and there is no Hibernate below JPA layer ?

Comment: I want to create a Jar File which connects database and if I put the folder to other pc, it should receive the database information. In my application, I use JPA and JDBC together. What should I do ? Which driver should I use ?

Comment: My application is desktop application(not web application).

Comment: When you run it directly using code from netbeans , does it run ?

Comment: Yes. If I open NetBeans, start the server and then click the jar file,  jar file works and I can write and read to the database. And it also runs directly using code from netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to derby+Netbeans, but from your explanation and this link -

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html#configuring

It seems you are using internal Java DB which comes with Netbeans Glassfish server.

Therefore when you start the server from netbeans it works.

Try external installation of database as shown in the above given link. It should work outside Netbeans.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I use external database, should I create embedded database ? And When I use embedded database, does it run on other PC ? As you shared link, it is not embedded database. I am going to create a database from JAVA DB and it is going to be located on my project folder. That sounds good. I am trying it.